# Does Google read text on my screen to improve near-future search results?

Tags: google-search

I've noticed that when I am reading about something online, and I open a new tab to google something was I reading about, whatever I had in mind comes up almost immediately in the suggestions.

For example, I was looking up the soundtrack to a tv episode. I was interested in one of the songs, so I opened up YouTube and started to search it. All I typed in was the first letter, and the song name was already at the top of the search suggestions. And this is an old, obscure song.

The only conclusion I can draw is that Google reads the text of web pages you have open, and uses that information to improve any near-future searches. Am I right? If so, what is this feature called?

Comment: If you got to a page via a Google search, they certainly already know the contents of that page. That seems like the most likely vector to me.

Answer (score 6):

Google does an impressive collection of data via searches, analytics and the other stuff, because "data is the new petrol".

I think the feature you describe is based on their [prediction engine](https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs)  for the auto-complete feature which is documented here https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/106230

> Where search predictions come from Search terms you type. Relevant
>   searches you’ve done in the past, if you’re signed in to your Google
>   Account and have Web & App Activity turned on. What other people are
>   searching for, including trending searches. Trending searches are
>   popular topics in your area that change during the day and aren’t
>   related to your search history. To get current trending searches, go
>   to Google Trends.

There you will find that some data is collected from the user activity in order to provide personalized results.

As Al E already said, they read the text regardless of your interaction with the page, the real question is "how do they make the connection ?"

Well, via "[Web & App Activity](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/54068?vid=1-635792448750307038-3310117812)"

> Your searches and browsing activity are saved in your Web & App
>   Activity when it's turned on and you're signed in to your Google
>   Account. This gives you better results and recommendations across
>   Google's products.